# Is it possible to migrate users with passwords from centos 6 to centos 7?

Tags: linux, centos

Is it possible to migrate users with passwords from centos 6 to centos 7? If yes - should it just work by copying passwd/group and shadow entries to a new system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Be careful to only copy your own users, not any system users.